# Store coordinates in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, coordinates, storage

From a set of code, I got an output of coordinates like

```
(448, 258)
(445, 362)
(426, 784)
(441, 496)
```

I need to store them in a dictionary. I want to iterate through the dictionary's elements after the coordinates stored in it. Also, the coordinates are not constant they may vary from one file to other(*the number of coordinates may change and value of 'x' and 'y' also*). So it should not be hardcoded. How can I make it possible using python? I am a noob, please guide me.

If it is not possible the coordinates are obtained from a function giving outputs of x and y. Can we form the coordinate dictionary from this?

Edit:

I expect the output as `{(448, 258), (445, 362), (426, 784), (441, 496)}` Also, have a doubt if I get the output as I expected can I make a loop through it like `for x in dict`?

The code follows

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time
import cv2
import os


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-y", "--yolo", required=True, help="base path to YOLO directory")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5, help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3, help="threshold when applying non-maxima suppression")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
counts = dict()

labelsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "coco.names"])
LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")

np.random.seed(42)
COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(LABELS), 3), dtype="uint8")
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolov3.weights"])
configPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolov3-320.cfg"])
print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]
ln = net.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416), swapRB=True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
start = time.time()
layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
end = time.time()
print("[INFO] YOLO took {:.6f} seconds".format(end - start))

boxes = []
confidences = []
classIDs = []

for output in layerOutputs:
    for detection in output:
        scores = detection[5:]
        classID = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[classID]
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
            (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")
            x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
            y = int(centerY - (height / 2))
            boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            classIDs.append(classID)

idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, args["confidence"], args["threshold"])

if len(idxs) > 0:
    for i in idxs.flatten():
        (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
        (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
        color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
        rectangle = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)

        x1= y+h
        y1= x+w
        coordinates = (x1,y1)
        print(coordinates)
```

I have written the print statement for knowing the coordinates of the boxes that was produced after the object detection.

Comment: Did you mean that you wanted to store the coordinates in a `list`?

Comment: actually a small example of expected output and behavior will be helpful.

Comment: I expect the output as 

```
{(448, 258),
(445, 362),
(426, 784),
(441, 496)}
```
Also, have a doubt if I get the output as I expected can I make a loop through it like 
``` for x in dict ```?

Comment: So, did you mean that you wanted to store the coordinates in a `set`?

Comment: @quamrana yeah!

Comment: Ok, but now you have to specify a sample input. You have shown some tuples, but where are they stored? Are they in a file, a string, or perhaps a list?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: @quamrana they are being stored as ```coordinates =(x1,y1)```.

Comment: So, you only have one coordinate then, not four or more?

Comment: @quamrana there is only one variable declared but the values of x1 and y1 have more values cause they are in a for loop

Comment: Ok, its definitely time for you to provide some sample code which produces the output you show at the top of your question, plus some code of yours to convert to a `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see you are just printing the coordinates out. You need to collect them as you go, so you might as well collect them directly into a `set()`:

```py
out = set()
if len(idxs) > 0:
    for i in idxs.flatten():
        (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
        (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
        color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
        rectangle = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)

        x1= y+h
        y1= x+w
        out.add( (x1,y1) )
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to take one tuple and seperate the element into a dict, this works:

```
t = (440, 765)
dict = {}
print(dict)
dict[t[0]] = t[1]
print(dict)
```

And the output is:

```
{}
{440: 765}
```

This should work as long as you are only giving it one tuple at a time, and none of the x-coordinates are the same. This could be re-rganized into a function like so:

```
def make_dict(tuple, dict):
     dict[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
```